# Excel COUNTIFS yields the same result with different criteria

Tags: excel, countif, sumifs

I used the COUNTIFS formula and received the same result despite using different criteria. Below is a simplified scenario and here's a [screenshot](http://www.ppmroadmap.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/excel.png) (sorry, newbies cannot post image).

> **Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E | Col F |**
>
> 8/31/12 | Yes | Step 1 | 0 | 8/31/12 | blank | 8/31/12
>
> 8/31/12 | blank | blank | 10,000 |
>
> 8/31/12 | No | Step 5 | 0 |

The intended logic is as follows:

- Criteria 1: include if column A matches "8/31/12" or cell F2
- Criteria 2: include if column B is "Yes" or blank
- Criteria 3: include if column C matches "Step 1"
- Criteria 4: include if column D equals "0"

Here's are the two formulas that both resulted in the same answer (count = 1):

- =COUNTIFS(A2:A4,F2,B2:B4,"Yes",C2:C4,"Step 1",D2:D4,0
- =COUNTIFS(A2:A4,F2,B2:B4,"<>",C2:C4,"Step 1",D2:D4,0

Also, any suggestions on tweaking the formula to SUM column D if criteria 1-3 are met?  Should I use SUMIFS?  I think so but the argument structure is different.

Thanks!

Comment: I just recalled that "<>" looks for non-blank cells not blank cells. Sorry for the interruption!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A4,F2,B2:B4,"<>",C2:C4,"Step 1",D2:D4,0`

should be

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A4,F2,B2:B4,"",C2:C4,"Step 1",D2:D4,0`

as `""` will count blanks, not `"<>"` for CountIfs / SumIfs

SUMIFS would be

`=SUMIFS(D2:D4,A2:A4,F2,B2:B4,"",C2:C4,"Step 1")`